# Mapa do Google não aparece

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, bootstrap

O mapa do google não está aparecendo no meu site.

Código:

```
<div class="row"> //O ERRO OCORRE QUANDO INCLUO A DIV MAP DENTRO DESSA DIV ROW
    <div id="map" class="col-6"></div>
    <div class="col-6">teste</div>
</div>

    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -8.607014, lng: -35.951444},
          zoom: 15
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Se eu não usar a div ROW, o mapa aparece normalmente, mas como quero dividir a tela em duas partes, quero fazer do jeito que está acima.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Verifica a altura da div, talvez seja necessário adionar um css height

Comment: **row** é o id ou a class row do bootstrap?

Comment: já está com o height, tanto que, quando eu uso fora da div, funciona de boa. row é a class, vou corrigir.

Comment: o height está com 100%

Comment: Tenta assim `<div class="col-6"><div id="map"></div></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O sistema de grid deve estar conflitando com a altura do mapa, troque isto:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="map" class="col-6"></div>
    <div class="col-6">teste</div>
</div>
```

Por isto:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
         <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">teste</div>
</div>
```